# Python: list.extend without mutating original variable

Tags: python, list, extend

I am wondering whether there is a way in Python to use `.extend`, but not change the original list. I'd like the result to look something like this:

```
>> li = [1, 2, 3, 4]  
>> li
[1, 2, 3, 4]  
>> li.extend([5, 6, 7])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]  
>> li
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I tried to google this a few different ways, but I just couldn't find the correct words to describe this. Ruby has something like this where if you actually want to change the original list you'd do something like: `li.extend!([5,6,7])` otherwise it would just give you the result without mutating the original. Does this same thing exist in Python?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think Python offers the `!` or not `!` options like Ruby has in its Array methods specifically.  Although, the answers below have alternatives to this ideology.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The `+` operator in Python is overloaded to concatenate lists, so how about:

```
>>> li = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> new_list = li + [5, 6, 7]
>>> new_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 4):

I know it's awkward but it works:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = list(a)
b.extend([4,5])
```

Comment: `b = a[:]` would probably be considered a better idea.